# Monitoring color changes in a specified area on the screen

Tags: colors, monitoring, pixel

I'm trying to monitor a list of items sorted by color in a vertical row in another application using visual basic.  The color codes are normally green but red ones are top priority and I send them out immediately.  This requires me to monitor the screen manually.  I want to be able to monitor a box spanning from the top of the list where the colors are to the bottom of the list for red orders.  I want it to alert me through a sound.  I also want it to continue monitoring and alerting in real time until I stop the program.

Ideally I want a gui with a button to start and stop the program.  I want the program to be able to run even if its not the top window because the monitoring window will have to be on top.

Only 2 colors show up so if red comes up at all I should be notified.  The position of the box I need monitored on the screen will never move from its position.

Thank you in advance.

Results is to be able to monitor a specific area for red.  Be alerted of red order.  Continue monitoring for new red orders.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words...

Comment: I can't send a picture due to the sensitive information on the screen.  I can find the coordinates for the area I want to monitor I just don't know how to write it.  I am really new to this.  I can make it work using individual pixels but not using an area.  Is there a way I can specify a certain area via a draw box?  then once the draw box is done, have it monitor for any red in that area.  I imagine making a static box would be easier since it never moves from its location on the screen.  setting specific pixels is time consuming and a lot of redundant code I don't want.

Comment: I suppose I could get away with doing individual pixels but I would have to code it for over 30 instances and I want to avoid that.